# mosquitto broker and web page

Tags: javascript, html, mqtt, node-red, mosquitto

I'm trying to connect my local web page to a mosquito MQTT broker on mosquito explorer.
I tried to use node-red with HTTPS nodes but it didn't work properly (I can receive data from the web page to the broker but I can't send it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg27H.png)from the broker to the web page).
I need help.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Envoi HTTP->NodeRed</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    Envoi HTTP vers NodeRed 
    <form action="127.0.0.1:1880/essaiNODERED" method="get"> 
      <label for="idTemp">Temperature :</label>
      <input id="idTemp" name="temp">
      <label for="idText">Entrez un texte : </label>
      <input id="idText" name="text">
      <button type="submit">Envoyez...</button>
    </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I can send the temperature value from this page to the MQTT broker using a simple node-red code but I can't do the opposite

this is my broker on MQTT explorer:

[image: image1]

this is the node-red flow that receives data from the web page to the broker:

[image: image2]

Comment: It's very difficult to help you without you sharing the least bit of code showing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71001626/edit) the question, do not try to add details in comments. you need to add a LOT more details. Please read the doc on what a good question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you probably don't using the approach you appear to be trying in the comment.

You have 2 choices

1. Totally remove the HTML form and Node-RED from the system and just use the Paho JavaScript MQTT client to connect directly to the mosquitto broker (after you have configured it to support MQTT over Websockets). That way you can both publish messages and subscribe to topics directly in the webpage.
2. If you REALLY must use Node-RED then you can use the WebSockets nodes to allow the page to connect to Node-RED and then you can send messages back to the page once they have been received in Node-RED using the MQTT nodes.

I suggest you use option 1 as it will be much simpler to get right.

This is totally based on the **very minimal** information you have provided. In future you must include a LOT more information in the question to start with.